# Windows Phone 8 app failed with FileLoadException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Xamarin app, which works perfect on Android and iOS, but when I am running it on Windows Phone 8.1 (real device, haven't tried emulator). It fails with

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{612EA9F2-DCC3-4580-8B14-389E6EF8E763}\Install\da-DK\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.resources.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Device.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{612EA9F2-DCC3-4580-8B14-389E6EF8E763}\Install\program.Xamarin.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{612EA9F2-DCC3-4580-8B14-389E6EF8E763}\Install\Xamarin.Insights.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Primitives.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{612EA9F2-DCC3-4580-8B14-389E6EF8E763}\Install\System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in program.DLL
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.XDocument.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Text.RegularExpressions.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

It successfully gets to the 1st page (login-page), and I investigated on the server, that it gets called with success and a token is send in response.

`program.Xamarin.DLL`  is an extension library I build, as it can be used in other projects.

Comment: Did you check is there any xamarin android or ios specific code or DLL's exists in your windows project?

Comment: Do you mean if all files (Renders and that like) that exist in iOS/Android project also exists in the Windows project?

Comment: Not all files.  Even any one file that specific to android or iOS library. Also, Are you working in Xamairn Forms or Xamarin Projects(Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS)?

Comment: I am working in Xamarin Forms. The only ones that does not exist is 2 renders, which only exist on Android.

Comment: I got the answer on another page. I was using an extension dll, that used other NuGet packages versions.

Comment: Where is a answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a secondary solution, be sure they both are using the same NuGET package versions.
This solved my problem